# restore from zfs incremental backup

Tags: zfs

I have create zfs backup in the following way:

1. create full backup
   `zfs snapshot pool/mydata@fullback`
   `zfs send pool/mydata@fullback > /backup/fullback`

2.create five incremenatal backup incr1 .. incr5
`zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incr1`
`zfs send -i pool/mydata@fullback pool/mydata@incr1 > /backup/incr1`

in a similar way the fifth incremental backup is

`zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incr5`
`zfs send -i pool/mydata@fullback pool/mydata@incr5 > /backup/incr5`

so now I have backup as
`/backup/fullback`
`/backup/incr1`
`/backup/incr2`
`/backup/incr3`
`/backup/incr4`
`/backup/incr5`

Suppose, I have to restore to a second incremental backup,
`zfs receive -F pool/mydata < /backup/incr2`
and rollback using,
`zfs rollback -r pool/mydata@incr2`
I got as expected.

But if I want to restore the fifth incremental backup after restoring to the second I got the issue.
How can I do this? Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `incr5` backup was taken against the full backup (ie: by issuing `zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incr5; zfs send -i pool/mydata@fullback pool/mydata@incr5 > /backup/incr5`) you can not restore it against another backup - namely `incr2`. To restore `incr5` you need to restart from a "plain" `fullback` restore.

In other words, you are not really using *incremental* backups, rather *differential* ones. For the latter, you need to always start from the last full backup.

Alternatively, you can switch to true incremental backup basing each new snapshot on the one before with something as the following:

```
zfs snapshot pool/mydata@fullback; zfs send pool/mydata@fullback > /backup/fullback
zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incr1; zfs send -i pool/mydata@fullback pool/mydata@incr1 > /backup/incr1
zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incr2; zfs send -i pool/mydata@incr1 pool/mydata@incr2 > /backup/incr2
zfs snapshot pool/mydata@incrN; zfs send -i pool/mydata@incrN-1 pool/mydata@incrN > /backup/incrN
```

For more information and advices on a reliable backup chain, I strongly suggest you to read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gbchx/index.html) and [here](https://illumos.org/books/zfs-admin/snapshots.html)

Comment: I can use differential one but my problem is I need to restore at any point. For example, if I first restore to a second incremental backup, I may again restore to the fourth incremental one. But the problem here is when I restore to incr2 and cannot do it again to incr4. It says like ```most recent snapshot doesn't match the incremental source```

Comment: @PratikGautam because, with the commands above, you must first apply `incr3`, and only then `incr4`. I suggest reading the linked docs and doing some tests.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It tried incremental backup and restore as you said. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it depends on whether you want to restore an entire snapshot (i.e. all the files in it) or one or more files within the backup.

In the second case (the one in which you essentially want to resume foo.doc, without the need to restore gigabytes of data) you can adopt a different mechanism: "freeze" the snapshots within a single archive (file), and then restore from the latter, in a similar way to how you would do with 7z or rar to understand with an example (a "snapshotted-7z/tar/whatever").

In your example I don't see a replica, but a real file-based backup (i.e. the zfs streams redirected to file).

If you use a FreeBSD system you can find a program already in the ports (archivers \ paq), it is called zpaq.

Otherwise you can try the latest version (7.15) or any more updated forks